# Use existing authenticated session from browser to perform https request on python

Tags: python, session, https

Is it possible to take an existing logged in session (say in Chrome) and pipe that session to a python script to perform an https request?

To  be clear on what I want to do, there's a website whose content can only  be accessed if you're logged in, however curling the credentials for simple http auth is not viable since it actually has captcha. So what I'm trying to do is, log in on say a browser, and extract that session to a python script, and request the url through that session. Am I making sense?

```
import requests

url="http://stackoverflow.com/"
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36"}
cookie = {
    "domain": ".stackoverflow.com",
    "expirationDate": "1427212131.77312",
    "hostOnly": "false",
    "httpOnly": "true",
    "name": "usr",
    "path": "/",
    "secure": "false",
    "session": "false",
    "storeId": "0",
    "value": "SOMEVALUE",
    "id": "5"
}

t = open("response.txt", "w")


t.write(requests.get(url, headers=headers, cookies=cookie).text.encode("ascii", "ignore"))
```

So I tried this out, and it doesn't seem to be getting me anywhere. If I look at the response, I see that it's actually the page without any user logged into it. Not sure what else am I missing...

Answer (score 3):

This should be possible if you reuse your browser's cookies and user agent. As far as I can see, any such solution would be browser-specific though: I have come across [a script](http://n8henrie.com/2013/11/use-chromes-cookies-for-easier-downloading-with-python-requests/) that uses SQLite to extract Chrome cookies and use them to make HTTP requests with the `Requests` library.

The script's `chrome_cookies` method returns a dictionary containing cookies. If you use the `Requests` library, you can pass the dictionary as a keyword argument when making requests:

```
import requests
import pyCookieCheat

url = 'http://www.example.com'

s = requests.Session()
cookies = pyCookieCheat.chrome_cookies(url)
s.get(url, cookies = cookies)
```

Comment: So say that I've extracted a cookie from a site in its dictionary form. How would I convert that dictionary (the cookie) back into a cookie object to pipe into a request.get(url, cookies=cookie)?

Comment: If you use the `Requests` library, you don't have to convert that dictionary at all: you simply pass it as a keyword argument when making requests. I've updated the answer with example code from the script.

Comment: Well, the cookie that I want to use in particular is in plaintext or dictionary form. how would I do it then? Also, it seems like the script won't work on windows...

Comment: To create a cookie manually for use with the `Requests` library: `cookies = dict(cookie_name='cookie_value'); s.get(url, cookies=cookies)`. If you have a cookie dictionary already, you can just pass it to `get` as is.

Comment: I tried also getting error saying syntax is wrong from this pycookiecheat lib

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you parse out the generated CAPTCHA, display the image and manually input the solution? It may be an easier approach to your problem than actually hijacking a session. Plus, it would result in a more portable and stable script (probably).

Comment: Hmm, that could be a possibility, but question, what would the request look like if we incorproate captcha? {user:myuser, password:mypassword, captcha:thecaptcha}?

Comment: My previous experience has been with CAPTCHA from third party websites, such that you send a POST to the CAPTCHA service and then another one to the target website with the login credentials and any other data necessary.

Comment: Your best shot is to capture packets sent during the login procedure. There should be a HTTP POST with form data (user, password, etc.). Check if the CAPTCHA data is there. If it isn't, then it must be in a different HTTP POST. Once you find those packets, just replicate the contents.

You can also look at the source and see how the form data is used to send the HTTP POST.

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
jar = requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar([
{
    "domain": ".stackoverflow.com",
    "expirationDate": "1427212131.77312",
    "hostOnly": "false",
    "httpOnly": "true",
    "name": "usr",
    "path": "/",
    "secure": "false",
    "session": "false",
    "storeId": "0",
    "value": "SOMEVALUE",
    "id": "5"
}]
requests.get(url, headers=headers, cookies=jar)
```

[@Stupid.Fat.Cat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1515864/stupid-fat-cat) Let me know what worked for you