# Is there a way to transfer a session from python to a browser?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to create a program that does several get and post requests to navigate a website automatically. After these requests are done, I would like to be able to then open the session in my browser to complete what I was doing programatically, but manually.

I have tried looking everywhere to no avail.

For example:

```py
def boring_stuff():
    s = requests.Session()
    try:
        s.get(do something)
        s.post(do something)
        #Here I want to then transfer this session to my web browser with a link so I can continue what the program was doing.
    except:
        print("timeout...")
    return
```

What I want is to be able to use some sort of cookies or whatever to transfer the session that was performing those actions to my browser.

Comment: Possibly relevant (but reverse) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26018944/use-existing-authenticated-session-from-browser-to-perform-https-request-on-pyth

Comment: I read through the documentation and it seems like that just works for loading cookies from chrome versus finding a way to, for a lack of a better term, embed cookies into links or browsers.

Comment: Well, it's loading Chrome's cookies as a database. So, could you add to the database yourself?

Comment: I see what you mean, using Selenium this seems to be possible. You can add cookies then open up the desired link and your webpage will be there. However, what I am attempting to do is perform these actions and generate a link and send that to my customers. Meaning the cookies would need to be affected on their machine as well. I know it sounds crazy, but I have seen it be done and I cannot understand how.